# Using USB port in android library module

Tags: android, usb, android-library

I want to create an android library module which uses USB port. This is important for me that my project is presented as android library. According to resources in web, i have to use UsbManager to get connected USB devices.

```
UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
```

Questions:

this means, I have to use an activity in my library?

Does it logical that i use an activity in my library?

what is the best solution for my goal?

I must say, i want to develop a library to communicate with USB smartcard reader.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would this require an activity? Yes, itll require a context, but thats reachable though many other options than just an Activity.

Comment: getSystemService is defined in Activity class. Can you present sample code that doesn't need to Activity? thanks.

Comment: context.getSystemService